# I need to use DATEDIFF to get the difference in minutes between the start and finish of a route patrol

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I'm trying to create a view that contains 2 coloumns, a PatrolID, and a numeric value representing the length of a patrol (in minutes). The patrol is marked as started in a TYPE coloumn with the variables PATROL_STARTED and PATROL_FINISHED. The time of these is clocked in a OCCURRENCE DATE coloumn with a timestamp (datetime).

I have attempted the following but it doesn't seem to want to work:

```
CREATE VIEW RouteDurations AS
SELECT PatrolID,
       DATEDIFF(mi, MAX(CASE WHEN ACTION="PATROL_FINISH" THEN [Occurrence Date] END),
                MIN(CASE WHEN ACTION="PATROL_START" THEN [Occurrence Date] END)
               ) AS Duration 
FROM [Data Import] AS t 
GROUP BY PatrolID
```

I cant for the life of me work out why not. Anyone pick anything up?

Comment: "doesn't seem to want to work" is a really poor description when, so far as I'm aware, this should have been producing an *error message*. If you have an error, please include the text of the error in your question. It might not mean much to you but it may mean a lot to those who answer your question, or for people searching for such problems.

Comment: Im new to SQL and the platform I'm running this on is not conventional (not publically available) and so error messages are not prevalent throughout. I will try and obtain an error message though, agree with you.

Comment: @gordon picked up the first error below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't use double quotes for strings.  Try this:

```
SELECT PatrolID,
       DATEDIFF(minute,
                MIN(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'PATROL_STARTED' THEN [Occurrence Date] END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'PATROL_FINISHED' THEN [Occurrence Date] END)
               ) AS Duration 
FROM [Data Import] AS t 
GROUP BY PatrolID;
```

In addition, the arguments to `datediff()` is first the start date and then the end date.

Comment: I tried that (with my correct coloumns in there) but it gives me an output of only null values in the duration coloumn, no actual amounts?

Comment: According to the text, the strings should be PATROL_START**ED**` and PATROL_END**ED**.

Comment: made the changes in the query and still returning null for all values in the duration cloumn. warning was also produced: "Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation". Could this be as a result of some patrols not having a 'patrol_finish' timestamp (ie remaining incomplete) in my dataset?

Comment: @Chen_Dogg . . . I suspect the problem is that the strings in the `ACTION` column don't match the ones in the query.  These have to be exact matches for the logic to work.

Comment: Correct. I've gone over and now it seems to be working. Must have been a string mismatch typo.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do a self join.  Something like this:

```
select p1.patrolID,
datediff(mi, p1.[Occurrence Date], p2.[Occurrence Date]) minutes
from [Data Import] p1 join [Data Import] p2
on p1.patrolID = p2.patrolID
and p1.action = 'PATROL_START'
and p2.action = 'PATROL_FINISH'
where p1.patrolID = something
```

Comment: Hmmm... what do I do with that something?

Comment: have run this removing the where clause and including a `Group By p1.[patrol ID], p1.[Occurrence Date], p2.[Occurrence Date];` at the end as I am creating a view, but I am only recieving blank values, much like the first answer